# Can I use an inlet with a 5-15R plug to connect a 120v 20A generator to a transfer switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, generator

I got a pretty modest generator in case we lose power this winter and I'm learning a bit about limitations of power, running the extensions, etc.  I'd like to wire up the house with an inlet and a transfer switch at the mains so I can throw a few outlets and lights on and hopefully the furnace or a/c.

The generator is a 1800w with two 120v / 20a 5-15R type outlets.  I'll probably call an electrician, but for my own knowledge, is it okay (per NEC) to wire the inlet with a 5-15R plug wired directly into the transfer switch?

All of the breakers on the board are 20amp (except for ac), so I suppose, it should be fine on the 5-15 type plug?  My concern is that the generator doesn't provide a 5-20R plug but it still puts out 20A. Is this a concern with the size of the copper in the wire, or just a nuance in the plug type?

Comment: An 1800w generator will not power much at once.  At most it can run one space heater and a couple of lights together.  You would need to turn off/disconnect heater to run a fridge or toaster oven, one at a time.  Would save my money and use a heavy duty(12 gauge) extension cord, till I got a bigger generator(8000w or bigger).

Comment: So don't even bother with an inlet / transfer switch?  I'm curious why a 1800w can't run a lot of stuff, shouldn't that be like plenty for multiple 10W LED bulbs and even a 300W fridge and then some?

Comment: I have installed a few generators for clients over the years. I have recommended a minimum of a 30 amp 240v inlet, mechanical interlock is the least expensive bolts onto a modern panel. But if your gen only has wiring for 15 amp it would be a code violation in my opinion with only 20 amp circuits, But that is just my opinion you would need to make sure your ground was s properly set up or the gen set ground floated to prevent a parallel path but your electrician should know this.

Comment: A space heater would be a very silly use of a generator.  It would be a "force multiplier" to use it for the blower and controls on the gas furnace.

Comment: Don't get one of those hokey 6-circuit transfer switches (or 8 or 10 circuit).  They cost far too much for what they do, and a generator interlock will do a much better job if your panel supports it.  You could feed one half your panel or the other... or possibly both depending on your panel's wiring.

Comment: You need a little help understanding generator output, Watts = Volts x Amps, so an 1800 watt generator at 120 volts equals 15 amps.

Comment: What all are you seeking to power off the generator, and can you post a photo of your panel please?

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  Turns out the the generator actually is 20W and as the combo 5-15 / 5-20 style outlets with the horizontal blade.  so not the worst thing in terms of compatibility.  But, still the same question applies, and sounds like an inlet may be overkill for this small sized generator, and I should wait till next generator upgrade.  Thanks again.